# In Ubuntu 22 file explorer GUI, how to add "Desktop" to left hand side shortcuts?

Tags: filesystems, gui, desktop

Have tried to search for it, but only get answers for the normal sidebar.

Here is a screenshot where I have opened the file explorer on my recent Ubuntu 22 machine:
[image]

How do I add a Desktop shortcut to the ones on the left?
(Starred, Home, Documents etc.)

I go to the desktop quite a lot, so would like it here. I remember this being the case on my previous ubuntu (non-22) machines.

Comment: The answer's in Ask Ubuntu SE site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422321/add-desktop-bookmark-to-nautilus-sidebar-on-ubuntu-22-04-as-it-used-to-be-in-18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on "Desktop" and begin to drag it a "New Bookmark" will appear in red in the sidebar. Just drag it to this position and release the mouse. The shortcut will be created.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to drag it just to the left hand side panel before, but you are right, dropping it at that slot works!